# I accidentally moved a temp .zprofile to my actual .zprofile's file

Tags: data-recovery, mv

My OS is MacOS Catalina. I was using a temporary .zprofile so I moved it to .zprofileold then moved .zprofilereactor to .zprofile but when switching back I accidentally moved .zprofile to .zprofileold overwriting my actual .zprofile, how can I restore my actual .zprofile?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148961/discussion-on-question-by-the-ah-i-accidentally-moved-a-temp-zprofile-to-my-act); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.